# Concatenar datos de un array PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Solicitando de sus conocimientos espero que me puedan ayudar con un problema. Tengo un `foreach` que recorre un array donde me trae 2 direcciones, pero están en divididas en diferentes keys. No siempre es la misma cantidad y no siempre terminan con la palabra Mexico, algunas veces termina con el , lo que busco es concatenar las 2 direcciones, quedando algo asi:

Direccion 1 : "La direccion 1 completa".
Direccion 2 : "la direccion 2 completa".

El `do-while` esta dentro del `foreach`

Codigo PHP:

```php
do {
    $addressOrigin .= $values[$i];
    $i++;
} while(strtolower(trim($values[$i])) != 'mexico"' 
    || in_array(strtolower(trim($values[$i])),$array_estados) 
    || in_array(strtolower(trim($values[$i])),$array_estados_abr)
);

$addressOrigin .= $values[$i];
$i++;

do {
    $addressDestination .= $values[$i];
    $i++;
} while(strtolower(trim($values[$i])) != 'mexico"' 
    || in_array(strtolower(trim($values[$i])),$array_estados) 
    || in_array(strtolower(trim($values[$i])),$array_estados_abr)
);

$addressDestination .= $values[$i];
$i++;
```

Ejemplo 1 del array:

```
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fecha de comienzo \ Tiempo
            [1] => Fecha/Hora de Termino
            [2] => Nombre del conductor
            [3] => Velocidad Promedio (km / h)
            [4] => Distancia (kilometros)
            [5] => Duracion (h)
            [6] => Direccion Origen
            [7] => Direccion Destino
            [8] => Numero de Vehiculo: 
            [9] => 15/10/2022 20:26:54
            [10] => 15/10/2022 20:40:57
            [11] => Empleado
            [12] => 4
            [13] => 1
            [14] => 00:14:03
            [15] => "Carretera a Salinas Victoria
            [16] =>  65500 NL
            [17] =>  Mexico"
            [18] => "Carretera a Salinas Victoria
            [19] =>  65500 NL
            [20] =>  Mexico"
            [21] => Resumen del  Vehiculo Numero: 
            [22] => Numero de Sesiones
            [23] => Tiempo Maximo (h)
            [24] => Tiempo Minimo (h)
            [25] => Tiempo  Total (h)
            [26] => Distancia Total (kilometros)
            [27] => Velocidad Promedio (km / h)
            [28] => 85
            [29] => 05:21:03
            [30] => 00:00:05
            [31] => 60:06:59
            [32] => 2281
            [33] => 14
        )
```

Ejemplo 2 del array :

```
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fecha de comienzo \ Tiempo
            [1] => Fecha/Hora de Termino
            [2] => Nombre del conductor
            [3] => Velocidad Promedio (km / h)
            [4] => Distancia (kilometros)
            [5] => Duracion (h)
            [6] => Direccion Origen
            [7] => Direccion Destino
            [8] => Numero de Vehiculo:
            [9] => 15/10/2022 20:26:54
            [10] => 15/10/2022 20:40:57
            [11] => Empleado
            [12] => 4
            [13] => 1
            [14] => 00:14:03
            [15] => "Carretera a Salinas Victoria 
            [16] =>  65500 NL
            [17] =>  Mexico"
            [18] => "Carretera a Salinas Victoria
            [19] =>  65500 NL
            [20] =>  Mexico"
            [21] => Resumen del  Vehiculo Numero: 
            [22] => Numero de Sesiones
            [23] => Tiempo Maximo (h)
            [24] => Tiempo Minimo (h)
            [25] => Tiempo  Total (h)
            [26] => Distancia Total (kilometros)
            [27] => Velocidad Promedio (km / h)
            [28] => 85
            [29] => 05:21:03
            [30] => 00:00:05
            [31] => 60:06:59
            [32] => 2281
            [33] => 14
        )
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Analizando tu estructura, se ve claramente que:

- `México` se encuentra en el índice `17` del array, entonces, puedes verificar el valor en ese índice directamente.
- Los otros datos de la dirección se encuentran en las posiciones `15`, `16` y `17`, los puedes extraer con `array_slice` y usar `implode` para mostrarlos como cadena.

Observa además que hay redundancia en tus datos y es algo que deberías corregir en el origen.

Dicho eso, así debería funcionar:

#### Código: [<kbd>**`VER DEMO`**</kbd>](https://rextester.com/OJM34844)

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if($item[17]=='Mexico') {
        printf("%s%s",implode(" ",array_slice($item, 15, 3)),PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Carretera a Salinas Victoria 65500 NL Mexico
Carretera a Salinas Victoria 2do array 65500 NL Mexico
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Estructura del array.

Viendo el resultado del array de ejemplo, veo que únicamente la dirección va entre comillas ("). Si es así, debería tener el siguiente aspecto:

```
$one = array(
    'Fecha de comienzo \ Tiempo',
    'Fecha/Hora de Termino',
    'Nombre del conductor',
    'Velocidad Promedio (km / h)',
    'Distancia (kilometros)',
    'Duracion (h)',
    'Direccion Origen',
    'Direccion Destino',
    'Numero de Vehiculo: ',
    '15/10/2022 20:26:54',
    '15/10/2022 20:40:57',
    'Empleado',
    '4',
    '1',
    '00:14:03',
    '"Carretera a Salinas Victoria',
    ' 65500 NL',
    ' Mexico"',
    '"Carretera a Salinas Victoria',
    ' 65500 NL',
    ' Mexico"',
    'Resumen del  Vehiculo Numero: ',
    'Numero de Sesiones',
    'Tiempo Maximo (h)',
    'Tiempo Minimo (h)',
    'Tiempo  Total (h)',
    'Distancia Total (kilometros)',
    'Velocidad Promedio (km / h)',
    '85',
    '05:21:03',
    '00:00:05',
    '60:06:59',
    '2281',
    '14',
);
```

El array 2 es igual que el array 1, así que hice una modificación y eliminé la key que tiene la palabra "México", ya que mencionas que en ocasiones no termina así.

```
$two = array(
    'Fecha de comienzo \ Tiempo',
    'Fecha/Hora de Termino',
    'Nombre del conductor',
    'Velocidad Promedio (km / h)',
    'Distancia (kilometros)',
    'Duracion (h)',
    'Direccion Origen',
    'Direccion Destino',
    'Numero de Vehiculo:',
    '15/10/2022 20:26:54',
    '15/10/2022 20:40:57',
    'Empleado',
    '4',
    '1',
    '00:14:03',
    '"Carretera a Salinas Victoria ',
    ' 65500 NL',
    ' Mexico"',
    '"Carretera a Salinas Victoria',
    ' 65500 NL"',
    'Resumen del  Vehiculo Numero: ',
    'Numero de Sesiones',
    'Tiempo Maximo (h)',
    'Tiempo Minimo (h)',
    'Tiempo  Total (h)',
    'Distancia Total (kilometros)',
    'Velocidad Promedio (km / h)',
    '85',
    '05:21:03',
    '00:00:05',
    '60:06:59',
    '2281',
    '14',
);
```

2.- Función.

Para reutilizar el código creé una función, Así no tendrás que llamar el `do-while` en cada ocasión aunque sí un foreach para imprimir los resultados.

```
function address($array, &$address){
    $preg = false;
    $str = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $pos = strpos($value, '"');
        if($pos === false){
            if($preg){
                $str .= $value;
            }
        } else {
            if($pos === 0){
                $str .= $value;
                $preg = true;
            } else {
                $str .= $value;
                $preg = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!empty($str)){
        $str = str_replace('""', '|', $str);
        $str = str_replace('"', '', $str);
        $address = explode('|', $str);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

3.- Imprimir el resultado.

La función, si no tiene direcciones retornará un `false`, de lo contrario genera un array con una o varias direcciones. Es por eso, que la recorremos con un foreach para imprimirlas.

```
echo "Array 1.\n";
if(address($one, $direcciones)){
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($direcciones as $key => $value) {
        echo "Dirección ".$count++.": ".$value.".\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No hay direcciones en el array 1.\n';
}

echo "Array 2.\n";
if(address($two, $direcciones)){    
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($direcciones as $key => $value) {
        echo "Dirección ".$count++.": ".$value.".\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No hay direcciones en el array 2.\n';
}
```

4.- Resultado.

```
Array 1.
Dirección 1: Carretera a Salinas Victoria 65500 NL Mexico.
Dirección 2: Carretera a Salinas Victoria 65500 NL Mexico.
Array 2.
Dirección 1: Carretera a Salinas Victoria  65500 NL Mexico.
Dirección 2: Carretera a Salinas Victoria 65500 NL.
```

Dejo el código de ejemplo completo en el siguiente link [EJEMPLO PHP](https://rextester.com/JRTQ95257)

Espero sea lo que necesitas, o al menos, te ayude en algo. Saludos.